# Media player null pointer exception

Tags: android, pointers, null, media

I have a really weird error that I just can't figure out what's going on. In my code, I use media player through SoundsClass like this:

```
public class SoundsClass {

private int sound;
private Context mContext;
public SoundsClass(int sound, Context mContext) {
    this.sound=sound;
    this.mContext=mContext;
}

    public void clickOnAndroid() {

      switch(this.sound) {
      case R.raw.sound1:
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.sound1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              mp.release();
          }
      });

      break;
      case R.raw.sound2:

       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.sound2);
       mediaPlayer.start();
     mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
             mp.release();
         }
     });
    break;
    case R.raw.sound3:
       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.sound3);
       mediaPlayer.start();
       mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              mp.release();
          }
      });
      break;
      }


    }
}
```

So, I use this class in my main activity like this:

```
    new SoundsClass(R.raw.sound1, getBaseContext()).clickOnAndroid();
```

On 2 places in this activity it works fine, but the third one gives a NullPointerException, caused by line in SoundsClass pointing to:

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Any idea why? Am I using MediaPlayer in a wrong way?

Logcat is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.testingapp.app.SoundsClass.clickOnAndroid(SoundsClass.java:42)
at com.testingapp.app.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:147)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Maybe I should add that I call this SoundsClass very often and with none or almost no pause in between. And sometimes I get:

```
bufferCount is to small and increased to 12.
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your activity code as well.. also, it would be a better practice to add the listeners to your players before calling start()

Comment: no, this it the entire mp code. I have not initialized it anywhere.  And I use mp while clicking on various buttons, no difference between 
them.
What listeners, could you elaborate a bit what would be a better practice?

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.view.SurfaceHolder)

The MediaPlayer.create call returns null if creation failed. This would be if it either cannot find the specified media or if the media is an invalid format.

Comment: Yes, I read API docs, couldn't find anything useful. I also tried changing the source (media), but with the same result.  I thought that maybe it has something to do with constantly creating and releasing MediaPlayer without regards to timing??

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.sound1);
while(mediaPlayer == null) {
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.sound1);
}
```